# Building a power supply for a Raspberry Pi 4 but having trouble with the output voltage of regulator

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, dc, raspberry-pi

I am using a LT1529-5 regulator to drop 12 V 2 A down to 5 V 3 A to power a Raspberry Pi 4 from a different wall DC power supply.

When my circuit is unloaded, the output is maintained at 5 V. When I plug in the Pi, It turns on for a few seconds then turns off.

I used an oscilloscope and found that the output starts constant at 5V for 2-3 seconds, drops to 4.6V, then moves back up and oscillates around 5V with the lowest point at 4.87V and the highest being 5.1V.

I am using a 44uF capacitor to try and smooth the output but it clearly isn't working. Can this be fixed by increasing the capacitor value? Or is there something else I can try?

I'll provide a link to the datasheet of the regulator I am using: [link](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1529fb.pdf)

Comment: That’s a linear regulator. It needs to dissipate (12-5)*3 = 21 W at full load. It can’t do that.

Comment: @LRV1o5 What is your question?

Comment: And a linear regulator is never going to take 2A in and put out 3A.

Comment: @VoltageSpike I guess my question is what I miss understood about the regulator if it is unable to take 12V 2A to 5V 3A. I'll drop a url to the data sheet I was going off. [link](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1529fb.pdf)

Comment: Please edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a linear regulator (type of regulators, not the manufacturer).

For a 3A output these require 3A input.

And that means to have 15W output, it requires 36W in, and dissipate the remaining 21W as heat.

And it can't handle being heated at 21W and it will shut down.

This is why converting 12V input to 5V 3A output is not done with linear regulators. They are unsuitable for that.